# No supported devices connected(Flutter/android emulator)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-emulator, development-environment

i tried youtube, researching using google, and even read a few threads on here but i didnt find anything which could help

im using a windows 10 operating system , ive used flutter on android studio and everything works fine, i enrolled in a course and the IDE used is VSCODE for flutter app development , whenever i try launching the emulator from cmd, it says "no connected devices" , i downloaded an extension on VScode and even when the emulated device is running and i type "flutter run" it still says no connected devices

im not looking to test this on a physical device and would rather use an emulator due to reasons

Comment: did you installed android studio for emulator  It's a simplest way to use emulator also you need to define environment path too then you can run command and it can hopefully do the job because this way i'm using emulator in ionic. hope it will help.

Comment: You should always list/link what you've tried, as I would ask what does `adb devices` say from the command line when the emulator is running. What does `flutter doctor` output?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you would have started the emulator before running the flutter run. I had faced the same problem earlier. I did these two things to make it work,

1. Setup path for in your system variables
2. Restart the system to bring this into consideration,

`https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config`

Comment: bud, i already did set up the path, everything to the letter, android studio everything works fine, but i dont know why the emulator cant be accessed from the terminal , i tried researching on youtube and google but still couldnt find something